# Why does my bake have imperfections?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

I'm new to blender, and this is my first model that I have made. I have just finished texturing my model and have combined the objects, and I would like to bake it onto another model to keep the materials to a minimum. I have followed this tutorial step by step:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq2tUT0iyCQ

The bake works, but every time I try to bake it the result has many imperfections and mixed colors and whatnot:
[image: Final baked image]
This is my final baked image, and if you look closely (especially on the top left blue thing which is the hat, and brown circle thing in the middle which is part of the dress), you can see clearly the random strings of color.
These are the main problems I have:
[image]
I don't know what is happening, I have searched online everywhere and I can't seem to find the solution. Please help!